# IP filtering on Google Cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have an Angular web app i want to deploy using Google Cloud run. However I need the app be visible only from a list of predefined IP addresses.

Can I simply set the ip allow/deny rules under Google cloud platform firewall or do I need another method?

Thanks in advance,

Nico

Comment: This is a good question (opinion).  I am assuming you are deploying your app to Cloud Run with an external (Internet) IP.  I wondered if VPC Service Controls applied ... but Cloud Run is not listed as a supported product.  Firewall rules (as I understand them) provide control over VPC access ... but I'm not seeing them being mentioned in the context of Cloud Run.

Answer (score 4):

[Google is clear about this point](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp/):

> Don't trust the network

By the way, the Google top priority in development don't rely on IP origin but on token for identity and authorization.

For Cloud Run, you have Google Front End (GFE) which act as proxy, check the authentication (in case of [private Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access)), ensure that the SSL certificate is deployed and valid,... It's not possible to customize it with IP filtering

Even if you plug a Endpoint (ESP) gateway in front of your Cloud Run service, it is not possible to filter on IP among all the [security method](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method). The easiest for your should be to use API key, I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1)

In the futur, Cloud Run will be compliant with Loadbalancer. Not sure that will be enough for filtering IP.

All of this for telling you that, if you want to implement IP filtering in top of Cloud Run (and Cloud Function), you have to implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to make Cloud Run accessible only for certain IPs.

However, Cloud Run services are deployed privately by default and are secured by [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access).

If you need to authenticate users, the provided ways are to use [Google Sign-In](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#using_google_sign-in) or, should you want to use other credentials, [Identity Platform or Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#using_or_firebase_authentication)